# How to pass string value from WidowsForm to ASP.NET MVC Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, winforms

I have seen couple of similar post but none of them resolved my problem, hence I am posting again.

I am trying to pass my WindowsForm data to a asp.net MVC controller.

But at controller I am receiving null value. How can I pass my windows form value (text value) to my controller? Kindly help.

Here are my codes:

**Windows form code:**

```
private void send_button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox1.Text))
        {
            var dataBytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(textBox1.Text);

            HttpWebRequest httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://localhost:61174/Home/DataFromWinForm");
            httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
            httpWebRequest.ContentLength = dataBytes.Length;
            httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";

            using (var dataStream = httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream())
            {
                dataStream.Write(dataBytes, 0, dataBytes.Length);
            }


            HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
            if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
            { starts_label.Text += "Posted";
                textBox1.Text = null;
            }

        }
    }
```

**And here is my controller:**
by Start method I am opening my windowsform application and trying to pass windows form text to my controller's DataFromWinForm method

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
    public IActionResult Start()
    {
        var appLocation = @"C:\Users\RFIDReader\bin\Debug\RFIDReader.exe";
        Process test = new Process();
        test.StartInfo.FileName = appLocation;
        test.Start();

        return View("Index");
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult DataFromWinForm(string receivedData)
    {
        //My code goes here
        return View();
    }}
```

But when my breakpoint hits at my controller I am getting null value
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this

```
 var dataBytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(textBox1.Text);
```

to this

```
 var postData = HttpUtility.UrlEncode("receivedData") + "=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(textBox1.Text);
 var dataBytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);
```

Comment: Thank You @Gökten Karadağ :)
I have modified your code a little. I have used "WebUtility" from "System.Net" Namespace instead of "HttpUtility"
Cheers!